# Table inside `tcblisting`

Tags: tables, tcolorbox

Suppose a) you are preparing a LaTeX manual and you wanted to exemplify a table and its source code side by side and b) you thought about using `tcolorbox` because of its features for handling similar situations (source code and its compiled result side by side or on top of each other etc.) with its `listings` library.

The following works fine:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings,skins,xparse}


\begin{document}

\begin{tcblisting}{}

    \begin{tabular}{lll}
        \hline
        texto & texto & texto\\
        \hline
        texto & texto & texto\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{tcblisting}
\end{document}
```

However, if I wrap `tabular` inside a `table` environment, the compiled result doesn't show up (only the code):

```
\begin{tcblisting}{}
    \begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{lll}
        \hline
        texto & texto & texto\\
        \hline
        texto & texto & texto\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{tcblisting}
```

Of course my goal is not letting the table float: my goal is just to optimize space and appearance by showing the aforementioned elementary table example side by side with its visual output inside a `tcolorbox`, as one can do with `showexpl`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{2pt}
\usepackage{showexpl}

\begin{document}


\begin{LTXexample} 
 \begin{table}
 \caption{A table}
 \centering 
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\hline        
texto & texto & texto\\
\hline
texto & texto & texto\\
\hlin
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{LTXexample}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Is there a way to make this work with `tcolorbox`? If yes, how?

Comment: This won't work if you want to show also the compilation. You need then to prepare the output externally. With `\begin{tcblisting}{listing only}` it works fine.

Comment: What is the purpose of letting the table float away if you want to display both code and output?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, actually just to show the result of the code side by side instead of using `minipages` or showing the code and then the actual table afterwards.

Comment: @Joseph: Yes, but this is pretty contradicting to use the table environment then

Comment: I don't know what is contradictory about showing the actual code for a table and the result side by side in a manual. Anyway, showing the said table below the code outside `tcblisting`, or using a `minipage`,  won't do any harm.

Comment: @Joseph: I explicitly wrote  `table`, not the `tabular` environment.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, I explicitly wrote `table`, too. Still see nothing "contradictory" about getting a full `table` environment example side by side with its graphical result. I know I can do it with `minipages` and `verbatim`. I just wondered why it didn't work with `tcblisting`. The `showexpl` package can do it with its `LTXexample` environment, but without all the bells and whistles.

Comment: `table` is a float environment. Do you want to disable floating for this environment?

Comment: @TeXnician, I wouldn't care if it didn't float, as long as it's visually equivalent to `table` environment.

Answer (score 2):

Here are two options:

- disable floating by emptying the table environment locally. This is okay, as long as the environment does not have a caption (simply redefining `\caption` to `\captionof` from the `caption` package does not work).
- using the `above*` key which allows even floating material, but beware of floating tables (it might not stay at the listing, but float away).

[image: non floating table]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings,skins,xparse}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcblisting}{listing side text, before lower={%
    \renewenvironment{table}{}{}%
}}
\begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{lll}
        \hline
        texto & texto & texto\\
        \hline
        texto & texto & texto\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{tcblisting}
\begin{tcblisting}{listing above* text}
\begin{table}[ht]
      \centering
    \begin{tabular}{lll}
        \hline
        texto & texto & texto\\
        \hline
        texto & texto & texto\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Quack}
\end{table}
\end{tcblisting}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution with `tcolorbox`. See section `15.7 Option Keys for Processing and Full Document Examples`.

A compilable document with a `table` is included into a tcblisting which will be processed during main document processing. This will create an external document which will be processed and its pdf result included as `comment`.

As we are only interested in `table` part of our external listing, we can select these lines with `firstline` and `lastline` options.

And as we are only interested in table, we need to `crop` the resulting document. This is done with `run system command` option. It's possible to use the automatically assigned names to external files, but I could resolve it, so I used the known name. In this case my file was `sensetitol-1.tex` and tcolorbox creates `sensetitol-1-listing-1.tex`. This was the name used as input and output parameter for `crop` command.

**Update**: [Thomas F. Stürm](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/30617/thomas-f-sturm) help me to solve the problem with the automatic names for external listings. with updated code there's no need to know the name of working file.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\makeatletter
\tcbset{%
    run pdfcrop/.style={%
        run system command={%
            pdfcrop\space\filename@area\filename@base.pdf\space\filename@area\filename@base.pdf}},  
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tcblisting}{%
    enhanced jigsaw, lower separated=false,
    leftlower=0pt, rightlower=0pt,
    colframe=red!50!black, colback=yellow!10!white,
    listing options={%
        style=tcblatex, texcsstyle=*\color{red!70!black}, 
        firstline=8, lastline=18},
    listing side comment,
    pdf comment,
    %freeze pdf,
    compilable listing,
    run pdflatex,
    run pdfcrop,
    %run system command=pdfcrop sensetitol-1-listing-1.pdf sensetitol-1-listing-1.pdf,
}
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{geometry}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{table}
\caption{A table}
\centering 
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\hline        
texto & texto & texto\\
\hline
texto & texto & texto\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
\end{tcblisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]