# How can I get a figure environment inside a tcblisting?

Tags: floats, tcolorbox

Consider this MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,etoolbox}
\PassOptionsToPackage{final}{listings}
\usepackage[%
   skins
  ,listings
  ,breakable
  ,xparse
  ,documentation
]{tcolorbox}

\NewDocumentCommand\MySmallFigure{o m m m m}{%
\begin{figure}[#2]%
  \parbox[b][][b]{78mm}{#3}%
  \hspace{6mm}%
  \begin{minipage}[b]{\dimexpr\linewidth-78mm-6mm\relax}%
    \caption[#1]{#4}%
    \label{#5}%
  \end{minipage}%
\end{figure}%
}

\AtBeginDocument{%
\newtcblisting[%
  auto counter,
  blend into=listings
]{codetext}[2][]{%
  label = #2,
  listing and text,
  #1,
  }}
\begin{document}

% This works
\MySmallFigure%
[anyone]%
{tb}%
{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}}%
{An image ....}%
{example-image-a}

% This doesn’t, since its a figure environment inside a tcolorbox.
\begin{codetext}{figure}
\MySmallFigure%
[anyone]%
{tb}%
{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}}%
{An image ....}%
{example-image-a}
\end{codetext}
\end{document}
```

I want to show the usage of the command `\MySmallFigure` and then the result of the command within a `tcolorbox`/`tcblisting`.

But ...

> ./tcbfigure.listing:1: LaTeX Error: Not in outer par mode.

... I am missing something, obviously.

Comment: just remove the `figure` environment. The purpose of `figure` is to take its content out of the document flow and allow it to float, but you don't want the image to float out of the box here.

Comment: The only other use of figure is to use `\caption`, which can be replaced by `\captionof{figure}{...}` (caption package).

Comment: ok, but then I cannot show the code `\begin{figure}...` what I want to do. In fact the figure environment is part of a (rather larger) `\newcommand` , which I shortend to the core. So I think it is important (for my purpose) to show the whole content of the `\newcommand`.

Comment: feel free to edit the question to clarify it (but the core of the answer has to be the same, you can not have a float inside any kind of box) But if you clarify the example to be closer to your use case, someone will suggest how to fix it.

Comment: you are right, that what I read about the floating environment inside a tcolorbox. I updated the question.

Comment: Maybe it is possible to find a solution that lets you use floats in `tcolorbox`es (I wouldn't know), but in situations like this I tend to fake the output https://github.com/moewew/biblatex-ext/blob/010e8b4581afcb2692dbc0846fcca43f8dd8c1bc/biblatex-ext.tex#L1598-L1610

Comment: That’s why everything seems to work in your documentations... faking it would be the ultima ratio then...

Comment: I know it feels wrong to fake these outputs, but for me there simply was a point where the code-as-displayed was not actually the code-as-executed in the lower part of the box and so I couldn't really think of a better way to solve this. While I think it is important to have good documentation I allow myself more leeway in the code I write for the documentation than for the actual package code. Compromises and quick and dirty fixes just seem more acceptable there.

Comment: I think that my solution for `tables` can be also applied to `figures`: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/448305/1952